# Is there any way to get keywords about a website

Tags: keywords

Is there any tool or service where I can put a website url and it will give me the keywords this site is known for or associated with. For example, if I enter http://stackexchange.com then it will give me keywords like "questions answers, software programming, mathematics" etc.

Comment: Subjective question, what really is a keyword? and how do you determine what you count?

Comment: The keywords can be of those as <meta name="keywords" content="blah blah blah">. what and how I will count that is not really necessary/related for this question I guess? But it would be nice if that tool/service have a API or gives result as json/xml.

Answer (score 1):

I use Market Samurai http://www.marketsamurai.com/ and SEO PowerSuite http://www.link-assistant.com/. SEO PowerSuite is more aggressive and spiders any site and analyzes the site fully, but it can take hours and even days (depending upon size) and you will need to deal with captcha which can be bypassed with an account. Market Samurai does give you link analysis for any site if you add it as a custom URL but uses a service (no cost to you) that may not be fully populated but is still good enough. Market Samurai does not otherwise analyze another sites keywords except for link analysis. It depends on what you need. SEO PowerSuite is incredible but will cost you time and money. There are also free online tools but often they are seriously lacking so I do not recommend them. I recommend trying SEO PowerSuite as a trial to see if it will give you what you want before paying for it.

Comment: I was trying to build a website categorizer from browsers bookmarks. So I was hoping I can get the website keywords from the urls and categorize them by those keywords. It seems that Market Samurai and SEO Powersuite won't fulfill my needs, if I'm not wrong.

Comment: You are right. These will not help. Look at the URL, page title, description meta-tag, and first h1 tag. These are often the best indicators. You can use PHP, Python, Perl, Java, and maybe Ruby to fetch any page and parse. You can parse HTML using XML methods to give direct access to HTML tags. You can also use a dictionary database to recognize words and chose which words to accept and reject.

Answer (score 0):

If you view the Source Code of the webpage, you can find a `<meta name="keywords" content="HTML,CSS,XML,JavaScript">` tag within the `<head></head>` tags if that site uses the `<meta name="keywords">`.

A side note about keywords:

Google, Bing, and Yahoo do not use those anymore to help index your pages. Pages are indexed using the actual content of the page. [Matt Cutts](http://www.mattcutts.com/)'s of Google has confirmed this in his [blog](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/keywords-meta-tag-in-web-search/).

Comment: Actually at first I tried this option but I found many sites are no longer using that meta keywords tag. For example, right this page of stackexchange contains no meta keywords. So thats the reason my question arises.

Comment: Meta Keyword is a WOMBAT (waste of money, brains and time). Let your competitors do SEO NOPs. The Meta Keyword faded into history a long time ago when porn sites found that putting "Oshkosh bGosh" in the keyword list netted them post pregnancy fathers and the search engines decided the only use for the meta was spamming.